# Custom currency in Drupal Commerce Shopping cart summary views

Tags: views, commerce

I need to display at the top of the default currency in drupal commerce view the specific currency at the Shopping cart summary view. 
Something like on the image
[image]

I tried to ad a custom field if footer tof that view but there is no currency options.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do this using Views PHP module. The variable $results contains the array of all the data.

For "Shopping cart form" and "Shopping cart summary" view you have to add to footer this to the output value of Global: PHP:

```
<?php 
$amount = 0;
foreach ($results  as $result) {
$amount = $result->field_commerce_total[0]['raw']['amount'] + $amount;
}
$converta = commerce_multicurrency_conversion($amount, 'HRK', 'GBP');
$formatcu = commerce_currency_format($converta, 'GBP');
echo $formatcu;
?>
```

To the "Commerce add to cart confirmation" you haw to ad to fields Global: PHP output code:

```
<?php
$amount = $data->field_commerce_total[0]['raw']['amount'];
$converta = commerce_multicurrency_conversion($amount, 'HRK', 'GBP');
$formatcu = commerce_currency_format($converta, 'GBP');
echo $formatcu; 
?>
```